# The Galois group acts on prime factors of an ideal of an integer ring as a permutation?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field extension with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ be the Galois group of this extension, and  for a rational prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ consider the ideal $p \mathcal{O}_K$. It can be shown that $p\mathcal{O}_K$ factorizes as a product of prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$, ie we have $$p\mathcal{O}_K = \prod_{i=1}^g \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{\mathfrak{p}_i}}$$

This factorization is unique up to permutation of terms. I have a couple of questions regarding the action of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ on the set of prime ideals $S= \{\mathfrak{p}_i: i =1,...,g\}$:

1. Why does the Galois group give a group action on this set?
2. Assuming that we have a group action is it true that its elements act as permutations of S?

For (1), consider a prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime over p in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Take any $\sigma \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$, then $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})\cap\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, and so $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}) \cap \mathbb{Z} = \mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z}$ as $\sigma$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence we see that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. How to proceed from here?

For (2) it would suffice to show that any $\sigma \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is injective. So suppose that $\mathfrak{p}_i \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$ are two prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$, such that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_j)$. Then as $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and so it is a fractional ideal, an inverse ideal $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)^{-1}$ exists. Multiplying the above equation by this inverse gives $\mathcal{O}_K = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i) \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)^{-1} = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_j)\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)^{-1}$. Now as $\sigma$ commutes with products, it also commutes with inverses, and so $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)^{-1} = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i^{-1})$. Hence we find $\mathcal{O}_K = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_j \mathfrak{p}_i^{-1})$. Now, I am a little confused if I can conclude from here that $\mathfrak{p}_j\mathfrak{p}_i^{-1} = \mathcal{O}_K$?

Are my above two attempts correct? How can I finish them?

Comment: All of the elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ are injective by definition. You need to prove that the action of this group on the primes of $K$ is transitive.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg, why do I need to show transitivity?

Comment: Because a transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is one such that for every $x, y \in X$ there exists $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$. In this case you show that for every prime $\mathfrak{p}_i$ there is a $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ such that $\sigma \mathfrak{p}_i = \mathfrak{p}_j$

Comment: Any time a group acts on a set, it permutes the elements of that set. So 2 is redundant.

Comment: Thanks @RghtHndSd I see it now, this makes complete sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part $1$: you have a group action given by $\cdot : \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q) \times S \to S : \sigma \cdot \mathfrak{p}_i = \sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)$.

Clearly $\operatorname{id}\cdot \mathfrak{p}_i = \mathfrak{p}_i$ and given $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ you have $(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2) \cdot \mathfrak{p}_i = \sigma_1(\sigma_2(\mathfrak{p}_i))$. Note that $\sigma_2(\mathfrak{p}_i)\in S$ because if $ab \in \sigma_2(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ then $\sigma_2^{-1}(ab) \in \mathfrak{p}_i$. Since $\sigma_2$ is a homomorphism we have $\sigma_2^{-1}(a)\sigma_2^{-1}(b) \in \mathfrak{p}_i$, and since this is a prime ideal we have $\sigma_2^{-1}(a) \in \mathfrak{p}_i$ or $\sigma_2^{-1}(b) \in \mathfrak{p}_i$, and hence $a \in \sigma_2(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ or $b \in \sigma_2(\mathfrak{p}_i)$.

For part 2: we show that this action is transitive on the primes of $K$ lying over $p$ (i.e. that the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ just moves the primes around).

Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}_i$ and $\mathfrak{p}_j$ are not conjugate by an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ so that for all $\sigma$, $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i) \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$. By the Chinese remainder theorem we can find a $\beta \in \mathfrak{p}_i$ such that $\beta \notin \mathfrak{p}_j$ for any $j \neq i$. Let $b = N\beta = \prod_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)} \sigma(\beta)$. Then $b \in \Bbb Z \cap \mathfrak{p}_i = p\mathcal{O}_K$. Now, for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ we have $\beta \notin \sigma^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_j)$ and so $\sigma(\beta) \notin \mathfrak{p}_j$. But we showed that $b \in p\mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathfrak{p}_j$ (since $\mathfrak{p}_j \mid p$) and since $b$ is a product of the $\sigma(\beta)$, this contradicts the primality of $\mathfrak{p}_j$, so it must be that there is some $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q)$ such that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \mathfrak{p}_j$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm not convinced that for part 2 you proved the right thing. Transitivity states something about the entire Galois group, whereas I only require that elements of it are permutations on S, ie. that's a condition on individual elems. Also, I'd find it helpful if you could spell out the 'standard' part of statement 1.

Comment: An action is just a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Sym}(S)$ so it gives you a permutation anyway. I'm just showing you in this answer that the action of the group on the primes of $K$ "moves **all** the primes around".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still a little confused why $\sigma(\mathfrak{p_i})\in S$. You showed that it is an ideal, but that doesn't mean that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p_i})\ = \mathfrak{p}_j$ for some j.

Comment: That part just shows that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ is a prime ideal. That $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \mathfrak{p}_j$ is shown in part 2.