# Why does the group acting on prime ideals need to be Galois?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions#The_Galois_situation), let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number fields, and $\mathcal O_L$ and $\mathcal O_K$ the respective ring of algebraic integers. If we assume that $L/K$ is Galois, then we can consider the group action of the Galois group $G := \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ on the ring extension $\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K$ to show that $G$ acts transitively on the prime factors $\mathfrak P_1, \dots, \mathfrak P_r \subset \mathcal O_L$ of $\mathfrak p \mathcal O_L$, where $(0) \ne \mathfrak p \subset \mathcal O_K$ is some prime.

My question is: Why do we need $G$ to be the Galois group? The standard proof by way of contradiction, using the Chinese remainder theorem, (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089618/)) would work for any group action with finite $G$ where $\mathcal O_L^G = \mathcal O_K$. One could even generalise this to any group action on finite Dedekind ring extensions $A \subseteq B$ and need not require any fields in the statement or proof at all.

Comment: If you don't assume that the group is Galois, then you lose out on the property that every $\sigma \in$ Gal$(L/K)$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{O}_{L}$.

Comment: @dormordo I think that's not true. For each $x\in\mathcal O_L$, there is an integral dependence relation $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$. But $f(\sigma(x))=\sigma(f(x))=0$ for all $\sigma\in G$ since $\sigma(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. So the group action is stable on $\mathcal O_L$ and each $\sigma$ induces an automorphism on $\mathcal O_L$.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake on my part, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise that $G$ is a finite group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$ such that $\mathcal O_L^G = \mathcal O_K$ implies $L^G = K$ and Artin proved that implies $L/K$ is Galois with Galois group $G$.

That is, if $G$ is finite group of field automorphisms of $L$ and we set $K = L^G$, then Artin showed $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension  and the natural mapping $G \to {\rm Gal}(L/K)$ is an isomorphism.  Artin's definition $K = L^G$ is, in your case, provable from your assumption that $\mathcal O_L^G = \mathcal O_K$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this proof works is because the norm is given by  $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/K}(\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Hom}_K(L, \overline{K})} \sigma(\alpha)$ (for a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$). If the extension is Galois, this is the product over all elements of the Galois group. If $L/K$ is not Galois, then $\prod_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha)$ might not lie in $K$, so you cannot conclude that this element lies in the prime ideal $p \subset \mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary for $N = N_{L/K}(\alpha)\in K$. It suffices to note that $N$ is a fixpoint, so $N\in \mathcal O_K$. Furthermore, $\alpha$ appears in the product of $N$, so $N\in \mathfrak P_i \ni \alpha$. Hence $N\in\mathfrak p$ and continue.

Comment: Alright, try making that work when $\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)$ is trivial, e.g. for $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $K = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But this example violates my assumption that $\mathcal O_L^{\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)}=\mathcal O_K$, since $\mathcal O_L^{\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)}=\mathbb Z[\sqrt[3]2]\ne\mathbb Z=\mathcal O_K$. In the end, I think that this assumption is equivalent to $L/K$ being Galois after passing the ring of integers to quotient fields, at least for finite groups.